# C# Child WinForm with elementhost distorts Parent Form in 150% display

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, elementhost

I'm trying to use an elementhost in my child form but it distorts my parent form. Tried to refresh and minimize/maximize the parent form but doesn't work. Take note this only happens when I'm in 150% display resolution. (you will need to change to 150% display then restart in order for this to replicate.)

[Parent form being distorted when opening child form with element host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBgoo.png)
[image]

Comment: How is it distorted exactly? Can you post an image of what you are expecting it to look like?

Comment: @vesan the parent form(smaller window) supposed to have the same font size as the child form (Front window)

Comment: Hosting Wpf controls (thus referencing Wpf assemblies), can cause you application to become Dpi Aware. And since it can... I wrote a description of this behaviour [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239138/dpi-awareness-unaware-in-one-release-system-aware-in-the-other?answertab=active#tab-top). See also the duplicate question marked by Hans Passant for handling it.

Comment: @Jimi Cool! the manifest or pinvoke works! Thanks a lot!