# How to avoid Winform auto resize resulting in controls cropped?

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize

I created a `Form` with fixed size, containing a fixed sized `TableLayoutPanel`. Controls are anchored to the `TableLayoutPanel` using the `Anchor` property. However controls are cropped after moving from Desktop to laptop.

I have tried setting `MinimumSize`, `AutoSize` and `AutoSacling` in `Form` and `TableLayoutPanel`, but controls are still cropped.

Suggestions?

Comment: It's a DPI Awareness simplex infection :) See this: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e?answertab=active#tab-top). Some notes I've written here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239138/dpi-awareness-unaware-in-one-release-system-aware-in-the-other?answertab=active#tab-top). Use the docking feature when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using Dock property of TableLayoutPanel.

Change its value to fill (Dock = Fill), this way your TableLayoutPanel will be drawn within the form border.

Another suggestion is, you should divide your main tablelayouttable like a grid and put one control inside its individual cell. Set their Dock property to Fill and you will see the result.

Hope it helps. Good Luck.