# WinForm is opening in large size than screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window form and here its main property

1. **windows state** to `maximized`
2. Auto size `true` and
3. AutoSizeMode set to `GrowAndShrink`

It is working  fine (opening in maximized size, fit according to screen) in my PC but when i am trying this application into another PC the form size opening in large size. It is maximized but its controls are in large size.
    Whats i am doing wrong?

Remember there are two screens attached and I have precisely mention (in Form load event) to my form that it open in specfic screen using this code snippet.

```
  int displayScreen = GetScreenNumber();
  this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[displayScreen].WorkingArea.Location;
```

Comment: Is you application DPI-Aware (set in the `app.manifest` or by other means)? If not, the Window is automatically virtualized. Does it also look somewhat *blurry*?

Comment: Frequent flyer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e?answertab=active#tab-top). [Some notes I've written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239138/dpi-awareness-unaware-in-one-release-system-aware-in-the-other?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: This is entirely normal, the monitor on that machine has a lower resolution.  The window is a lot bigger as well, but you can't see that because you maximized it.  Programmers tend to have nice high resolution screens, that doesn't exactly help them create UI that scales well.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the minimum and maximum size of form as shown below

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(140, 480);
this.MaximumSize = new Size(140, 480);
```

You can also use it as below

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int h = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
            int w = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
            this.ClientSize = new Size(w, h);
        }
```

Another way it can work for you is the

```
Rectangle screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
int w = Width >= screen.Width ? screen.Width : (screen.Width + Width) / 2;
int h = Height >= screen.Height ? screen.Height : (screen.Height + Height) / 2;
this.Location = new Point((screen.Width - w) / 2, (screen.Height - h) / 2);
this.Size = new Size(w, h);
```