# How to take a full screenshot in VB Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Wanting to create a system that allows me to take full screen shots, I looked at some threads on SO and other sites and have tried everything they are doing, however for some reason, I cannot take a screenshot any larger than 1536 x 864. Even using my region selector tool. Heres the code I am using to take the full screen screenshot:

```
Dim ClipicScreenshot As Bitmap
    Dim Graphic As Graphics
    screenshot = New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Primary.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Primary.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Graphic = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    Graphic.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, My.Computer.Screen.Primary.Bounds, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    My.Computer.Clipboard.SetImage(ClipicScreenshot)
```

I have tried specifying the bounds of my screen (1920 x 1080) but still i only get a max image size of 1536 x 864.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Research making your application DPI Aware.

Comment: Your application is, most pobably not DPIAware. See this: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e?answertab=active#tab-top). Som notes I've written: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239138/dpi-awareness-unaware-in-one-release-system-aware-in-the-other?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Some other notes on [System Displays disposition and VirtualScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012896/c-sharp-user32-using-setwindowpos-with-multiple-monitors?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Ahh! That would most likely be it. I have a High DPI display. After enabling DPI Awareness I was able to get it to work. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e)

Comment: Uhh I dont think so. I was asking how to take a screenshot and at the time of creating this thread, I was unaware it was DPI Aware related. So this question is different