# C# Screenshot Full Window

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm trying to write a console app using .NET Framework. I want to screenshot my screen. I've used other answers on SO like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24879511/9457997

The issue is that this doesn't capture my whole screen. It's missing about 1/5 on the bottom and the right side.

How can I capture my whole screen using C# .NET Framework?

Comment: If the screen your're trying to take a picture of is set to scale and your application is not DPIAware, you will receive *virtualized* measures (scaled to a predefined DPI value). First, try setting your app's DPI Awareness to at least System Aware. See here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103) how to *activate* it. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103) for further details on specialized API functions.

Answer (score 5):

Use [VirtualScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

// Create a bitmap of the appropriate size to receive the full-screen screenshot.
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
{
    // Draw the screenshot into our bitmap.
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
    }

    //Save the screenshot as a Jpg image
    var uniqueFileName = "C:\\temp\\a.Jpg";
    try
    {
        bitmap.Save(uniqueFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;` to get the bounds of your screen.

```
Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    bitmap.Save("C://test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

You will need to reference `System.Drawing`, `System.Drawing.Imaging` and `System.Windows.Forms` for this code sample to work in a Console application.

Answer (score 0):

I have unfortunately not found a way to screenshot from a console application, but here is my way to screenshot and let the user pick where to save the pic by using `SaveFileDialog`.

For the following code, you will need these three references:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

You can attach this code to a button or an event:

```
Bitmap bt = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bt);
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bt.Size);
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.ShowDialog();
string name = sfd.FileName + ".jpg";
bt.Save(name, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// Capture the screen
Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screenshot.Size);

// Display the screenshot on the picture box
pictureBox1.Image = screenshot;
```