# Winform with embedded wpf rescales on displays with higher than 96 DPI

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a windows form with a control that inherits System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost and when that form is initialized on displays with higher than 96 DPI the application rescales down to about 2/3rd's of it's original size. I've set the application DPIAware = true in an app.manifest but that did not solve the issue. I am wondering if there is a way to get the application to not rescale, or if it does, to do so at 96DPI?

Comment: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103). Read the notes about the `app.manifest` then go to the last line.

Comment: That did the trick! Great write up, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome :)