# How can I handle Windows scaling from a WinForm with an embedded WPF UserControl (which was instantiated from an Excel VSTO add-in's ribbon)?

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, winforms, vsto

### Context

We have a problem with the Windows scaling feature (100%, 125%, 150% ...) and our WinForm. We instantiate our WinForm from an Excel VSTO Add-in, and each WinForm contains a single component which is a `UserControl` (WFP) hosted with an `ElementHost` in the WinForm.

Each `UserControl` embeds all the necessary components, with an MVVM approach.

The problem occurs only when the user has two screens and the main screen has a zoom scale of `100%` and the secondary screen is on `125%` or more.

[image]

#### Excel Ribbon.cs

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var form = new MainForm();
    form.Show();
}
```

#### MainForm.cs

```cs
public MainForm()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.MainUserControl = new MainUserControl();
    this.Controls.Add(new ElementHost 
    { 
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
        Child = this.MainUserControl 
    });
}
```

### Expected behavior:

[image]

### Actual behavior:

[image]

The problem only occurs on the main screen (this screen was set to `100%` scale) but not on the second screen.

#### Other information

Another interesting point is that when we move the WinForm from the main screen to the second screen, it displays correctly; and then we move it from the second screen to the main and that's functional.

At this point, if we try to resize the WinForm then it breaks again.

### What I've allready try:

First of all we tried to add a app.manifest and uncomment the DPI Aware block

```xml
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

We also uncomment the compatibility support for Windows 10 (all our collaborators are under W10, no need to support more)

```xml
<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
```

We trying to added the two following methods on the Addin Startup event, but without any results

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Also we've got the following line in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`

```cs
[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]
```

Comment: Read the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103) and here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103).

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Jimi, we tried many of what is said in the different notes, but nothing helps us to fix the problem.I edited my post to notify what we tried.

Comment: If you're *embedding* a component that is not DPIAware, that object is subject to virtualization (the System will size it for you (or paint it, if you will), since the object is not *Aware* (Aware means *Dont bother, I'll do it myself*). All components need to follow the same Awareness status and type (SystemAware, PerMonitor, PerMonitorV2 etc.). You cannot enable DPIAwareness in the manifest and add `System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness` at the same time, if that's what you did. Make everything DPIAware. You'll have to re-layout a couple of things, but that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue look similar to this! The only thing I did was set the AutoScaleMode in the Properties of the WinForm to Font instead of Inherit and it fixed my problem without adding DPI Awareness!

Comment: Huy thank you is this still working well for you?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using windows form, why not use WPF directly.
It handle scaling issue by itself.