# VB.NET "Enable application framework" with side by side assembly

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2003, side-by-side

I am facing very odd problem here.
I have a VB.NET application where I am using Native (VB6) COM Component with side by side assembly. (using exe manifest file)
All is working fine if I uncheck  "Enable application framework" in project settings. Application is working fine on Windows 2003 with side-by-side COM (no need to register dll).

But if I enable application framework then one of my old server Windows 2003 is not able to loading the application because it is not able to find "Microsoft.Windows.Common-controls" version 6.

My question is what does "Enable application framework" do? I am not able to get much information about how does it changes assembly reference in the application?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 has been end of life for several years now. This means it no longer receives _any_ updates: **not even critical security fixes**, of which there are now numerous outstanding. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using that server. Getting up to a supported OS is job #1 here, and once you accomplish that the question itself is likely moot.

Comment: While what Joel says is very true, I also understand that it might simply be out of your control.  This link think explains it pretty wellhttps://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/enable-the-application-framework-in-vb.aspx but not really to sure what the relevance to you issue is

Comment: This other question shares a similar implication that use of the application framework affects how the manifest is generated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318170/dpiaware-and-enable-application-framework-at-application-settings

Comment: My suggestion is to inspect the manifest file itself and see what the differences are when the option is/is not selected. If its an external manifest you can just open it in any text editor (its XML). If its an embedded manifest see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798693/3195477 but the quick tip is to just load the entire EXE into notepad and scroll to the end (seriously)