# Scaling issue while running program (visual studio 2017)

Tags: vb.net, scaling

Its probably best to mention first this issue is on a school system.

The issues is that when i start my program, the first form is fine but the second form scales very strangely so everything is small and blurry.

When I open my project I get a message saying my main display is set to 200% so I click the link to restart with 100% but the problem persists,

this issue suddenly appeared without me changing anything which leads me to believe it's an issue with the school system but I'm unsure and would be welcome to any suggestions.

Comment: Are you using WinForms?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What means "scales very strangely"? Could you link screenshots? What do you use for displaying the forms? Could you provide some code?
I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If this is a WinForms project (you always need to specify the UI platform in use), read the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103). You may find the reason why one Form is, apparently, treated as DpiAware and the other one is not.