# How to avoid cross-thread operation not valid exception in Winform service bus message receiver

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, servicebus, ui-thread

Have developed an Azure service bus message receiver console app which is working fine [console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrTPe.png).

Code for console app as follows:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sbusnsXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=bkjk3Qo5QFoILlnay44ptlukJqncoRUaAfR+KtZp6Vo=";
        const string queueName = "bewtstest1";
        var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

        try
        {
            queueClient.OnMessage(message => {
                string body = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();                                        
                Console.WriteLine(body);
                message.Complete();                    
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            queueClient.OnMessage(message => {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                message.Abandon();                    
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }            
    }
}
```

Have tried to convert to a WinForms app, so I can show the service bus message as a string in a ListBox.
I have created a new Class (`Azure`) with the console app code, and call the method in the main form.

**Class Azure**:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public class Azure
{
    public static void GetQueue(Form1 form)
    {
        const string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://sbusnsXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=bkjk3Qo5QFoILlnay44ptlukJqncoRUaAfR+KtZp6Vo=";
        const string queueName = "bewtstest1";
        var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

        try
        {
            queueClient.OnMessage(message => {
                string body = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
                //Form1 f = new Form1();                
                form.listBox1.Items.Add(body);
                Console.WriteLine(body);
                message.Complete();
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            queueClient.OnMessage(message => {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                message.Abandon();
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Form:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Azure.GetQueue(this);
    }
}
```

The code compiles, however when a new service bus message is received I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control 'listBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.'

Any thoughts on how I can avoid this exception (note I have tried using `InvokeRequired` but can't get the code to compile)?

(Feel like I'm close as when I stop and re-run the program, the form loads with the message in the ListBox as shown here: [listbox with message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfwqX.png)!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you cannot reference a Control created in the UI Thread from another thread; as you have noticed, a `Invalid Cross-thread operation` exception is raised when you try to: a Windows Forms app must be single-threaded, the reasons are well explained in the [STAThreadAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stathreadattribute) documentation.

**Note**: Remove all **`Console.ReadLine()`**, you cannot use that in WinForms (there's no Console).

Here some implementations that may work for you, in order of relevance in your context (well, that's what I think, at least. You pick what you prefer).

▶ [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1): this class is really simple to use. You just need to define its return type (the `T` type, it can be anything, a simple `string`, a class object etc.). You can define it in-place (where you call your threaded method(s)) and pass its reference. That's all.
The method that receives the reference calls its [Report()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1.report) method, passing the value(s) defined by `T`.
This method is executed in the Thread that created the `Progress<T>` object.
As you can see, you don't need to pass a Control reference to `GetQueue()`:

Form side:

```
// [...]
var progress = new Progress<string>(msg => listBox1.Items.Add(msg));

Azure.GetQueue(progress);
// [...]
```

Azure class side:

```
public static void GetQueue(IProgress<string> update)
{    
    // [...]
    try {
        queueClient.OnMessage(message => {
            string body = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            update.Report(body);
            message.Complete();
         });
    }
    // [...]
}
```

---

▶ [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) (`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`) [Post()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post): this class is used to sync threading contexts, its `Post()` method dispatches an asynchronous message to the synchronization context where the class object is generated, referenced by the [Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) property.
Of course, see [Parallel Computing - It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext).

The implementation is no much different than the previous: you can use a Lambda as the `SendOrPostCallback` delegate of the Post() method.
An `Action<string>` delegate is used to post to the UI Thread without the need to pass a Control reference to the `Azure.GetQueue()` method:

Form side:

```
// Add static Field for the SynchronizationContext object
static SynchronizationContext sync = null;

// Add a method that will receive the Post() using an Action delegate
private void Updater(string message) => listBox1.Items.Add(message);

// Call the method from somewhere, passing the current sync context
sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
Azure.GetQueue(sync, Updater);
// [...]
```

Azure class side:

```
public static void GetQueue(SynchronizationContext sync, Action<string> updater)
{    
    // [...]
    try {
        queueClient.OnMessage(message => {
            string body = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            sync.Post((spcb) => { updater(body); }, null);
            message.Complete();
         });
    }
    // [...]
}
```

---

▶ [Control.BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke):  you can use `BeginInvoke()` to execute a delegate (usually as a Lambda) asynchronously on the thread that created a Control's handle.
Of course, you have to pass a Control reference to the `Azure.GetQueue()` method.
That's why, in this case, this method has a *lower preference* (but you can use it anyway).

<sub>`BeginInvoke()` doesn't require to check `Control.InvokeRequired`: this method can be called from any thread, including the UI Thread. Calling `Invoke()` instead requires that check, since it could cause a dead-lock if used from the UI Thread</sub>

Form side:

```
Azure.GetQueue(this, Updater);
// [...]

// Add a method that will act as the Action delegate
private void Updater(string message) => listBox1.Items.Add(message);
```

Azure class side:

```
public static void GetQueue(Control control, Action<string> action)
{    
    // [...]
    try {
        queueClient.OnMessage(message => {
            string body = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            control.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> action(body));
            message.Complete();
         });
    }
    // [...]
}
```

---

You can also use [System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher) to manage a Thread's queued work items, calling its `BeginInvoke()` (preferable) or `Invoke()` methods.
Its implementation is similar to the `SynchronizationContext` one and its methods are called as the `Control.BeginInvoke()` method already mentioned.

I'm not implementing it here, since the Dispatcher requires a reference to `WindowsBase.dll` (WPF, usually) and this can cause *undesired effects* in a WinForms application that is not DpiAware.
You can read about this here:
[DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103)

Anyway, in case you're interested, let me know.