# C# .NET MediaPlayer automatically resizes form (only visually)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm making a simple program in `C#` `.NET-Framework`, and for sound I'm using the (WPF-component) MediaPlayer (*because of the many benefits over SoundPlayer*). But when I'm using the dedicated code in my program, it rescales the forms (makes it atleast 30% smaller), making the text unreadable and the form visually unusable.

These are my settings for my Form:

`Non-sizable`
`Custom minimize and close buttons`
`Size: 1150 x 800`
`Form borderstyle: None`

And this is the code that I'm using to play sound (simplified):

```
using System.Reflection; // for URI code
using System.IO; // for URI code
using System.Windows.Media;

string soundURI = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Click1.wav"); //gets the sound URI  
MediaPlayer sound = new MediaPlayer();

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    sound.Open(new Uri(soundURI));  
    sound.Play();  
}
```

When I run the code, my form automatically resizes to something smaller than `1150 x 800`, but it does not update the `this.Width` or `this.Height`, so it's only visual. When I exclude the usage of MediaPlayer, the form size acts how it's supposed to act.

I now know that it's the MediaPlayer that causes this problem. Not using MediaPlayer would be the last option, but I could not find a fix for this problem online, and I don't know what's causing this behaviour (from MediaPlayer). What might be causing this?

Comment: [DPI Awareness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239138/dpi-awareness-unaware-in-one-release-system-aware-in-the-other/50276714#50276714)

Comment: I created a MediaPlayer in my test, but it works fine and not resizes the form. The size is always maintained at 1150, 800. To reproduce the issue, did you miss some steps?

Comment: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103). If you don't want to make your app DpiAware, the counter-measure is the code snippet in the last line.