# Using System.Windows.Media API in a Winforms application results in weird UI behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am trying to use `System.Windows.Media.Typeface` to get some details of a font.
When I use it in my `WinForms` application the UI is resizing and the fonts are changing.
I noticed that my display resolution is at 125%. When I test this on 100% screen it does not happen.

Is there any issue of referencing PresentationCore.Dll in a winforms app. Or is
it about Typeface class.

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class WinFormample : Form
    {
        public WinFormample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Typeface t = new System.Windows.Media.Typeface("Arial");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103). In short, when you reference PresentationFramework assemblies, your WinForms app, if not already DpiAware, will become DpiAware (`SystemAware`). You either make your app DpiAware (you really should) or disable the automatic feature, as described in the last paragraph.