# Jumplists in VB.NET Windows Form Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, jump-list

Is there a way to create Windows Taskbar jumplists in a VB.NET Windows Form Application?  I'd like to add my last opened files to the list.

I've done a bunch of searching and can find this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0, but I can't figure out how to get System.Windows.Shell to be accessible in my application.  It says the namespace can't be found.

Any direction you can point me would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a reference to PresentationFramework.dll in your project?

Comment: That page is for WPF/UWP so I'm not sure that it will work at all in WinForms. It's worth trying out but you may need to at least make significant changes.

Comment: [Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) (target .Net Framework 4.8)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask a follow up question.  Please let me know if not.  I as able to get this sort of working by adding the reference to PresentationFramework.dll.  What's happening now is anytime I call things related to System.Windows.Application, the fonts of my gui look much smaller than normal.  Is that a WPF vs Winforms thing?

Comment: Just made a blank winforms project.  Anytime I add the reference to PresentationFramework.dll, the GUI looks totally different (smaller size/fonts).  What's up with that?

Comment: Read the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103). If you want to disable automatic the DpiAwarenes introduced by referencing `PresentationFramework` assemblies, skip to the last paragraph. -- I suggest to make your app DpiAware regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got working:

```
Dim a As System.Windows.Application = System.Windows.Application.Current
If a Is Nothing Then a = New System.Windows.Application

Dim currJumpList As System.Windows.Shell.JumpList = JumpList.GetJumpList(a)
If currJumpList Is Nothing Then
    currJumpList = New JumpList
    JumpList.SetJumpList(a, currJumpList)
Else
    currJumpList.JumpItems.Clear()
End If

Dim jumpTask As JumpTask

jumpTask = New JumpTask
jumpTask.Title = "This is what gets shown to the user"
jumpTask.Description = "This is what the user sees if they hover or the item"
jumpTask.ApplicationPath = "pathToYourEXE"
jumpTask.Arguments = "Your arguments"
jumpTask.CustomCategory = "The category header"
currJumpList.JumpItems.Add(jumpTask)

currJumpList.Apply()
```

Important Notes:

- You'll need to add a reference to PresentationFramework.dll.  If your in Visual Studio, its in the Framework section.
- its really important to call the Apply() after you make changes to the JumpList.
- if you are winforms, the moment you add a reference to you PresentationFramework, you'll notice the appearance of your GUI changes.  This appears to be releated to DPI awareness.  To fix, Go to your Project Properties --> Application --> View Windows Settings.  This should bring up your app.manifest.  In there, you'll see a commented section on dpiaware.  Uncomment the entire section.  Play with setting the value to true / false.  I found that false would keep the GUI looking like it used to, while true improved the clarity of the fonts in my GUI.  Either value should fix the issue though.