# A Gap When Adding WPF UserControl To Windows Form

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, xaml, wpf-controls

[image: Image Of UserControl While In Design Mode]

Code For UserControl In Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="90" d:DesignWidth="90">

<Grid Background="Yellow" >
    <Canvas Name="T3Spark">
        <Polygon Fill="Red" Points="10,10,10,10 10,80,80,10"></Polygon>
    </Canvas>
</Grid><UserControl>
```

What I Don't Understand Is: Why's There A Gap When I'm Adding The Usercontrol To My Windows Form And How To Remove It?

[image: Image Of When Adding The UserControl To The Form.]

Comment: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi - My Both Projects Are Set To Be Dpi Aware But Still, The Problem Persists.

Comment: In Design mode? It looks like you're not designing a 100% scale. The other information is for Run-time mode.