# Bug in form scaling with FontAwesome.Sharp

Tags: c#, winforms

My project contains 2 Forms, one is the `LoginForm`, other is the `MainForm`
The `LoginForm` will do this when login button is clicked and assume it is a successful login:

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm ();
this.Hide();
mainForm.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

This is my login form when I run the program (it is correct):

[image: Image1]

when I login, this is the `MainForm`:

[image: Image2]

it shrink, it should look like this:

[image: Image3]

then I hit the log out button from `MainForm` (it execute `this.close()`), the login form reappear, but now it is look like this:

[image: Image4]

way smaller and not even in the center of the desktop as I set them to be in properties.
But somehow, my friend who ran the program on a 12.5 inch laptop (1366 x 768 resolution), all the things is perfectly fine, mine is 14 inch (1920 x 1080) get the above problems.
The IconButton from FontAwesome cause this, it's all good after I remove all IconButton from the forms

Comment: Read the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103) and also take a look at the marked duplicate. Since you're probably targeting .Net Framework, read this: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) -- You should always specify the .Net version in use.

Comment: I do what the links says but it is still shrinking

Comment: I have no idea what you have done. Add the information to the question.