# problem with spaces between text and image in buttons

Tags: vb.net

- when I Run the project the spaces between Image and text increase I
  don't know why and this problem  in every button in my project
- the first Image show the button and properties before Run
- the second Image show spaces between text and image after run
  [image]
- here is the Image after Run

[image]

Comment: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: thank you For respond . But can you explain to me what do you mean ? did you know my problem cause ?

Comment: Is your app Dpi-Aware? What I see in the image suggests it's not. Make sure you enable that as the link says (Skip the manifest step). Make sure your forms `AutoScaleMode` properties are set to `Dpi`. And don't scale your development environment. Should 100%. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/14171304) for more.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/14171304) another one.

Comment: You have set `TextAlign` to `MiddleRight`. Try to set it to `MiddleLeft` (I don't know how this behaves with right-to-left scripts however).

Comment: thank you Dr.null it's solved  i did it DPI