# Scaling issues, not sure where to begin

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scaling, dpi

We have a rather large, and a bit old winforms project that we developed and maintain.

One of our users has started getting scaling issues, where the grids, text, buttons etc are all a bit too large.

I should note that it seems to be just one of the forms (or its child forms) that activates the issue, as when he first starts the program, he doesn't have it. Only upon opening said form, does the issue begin, and "infect" the rest of the program.

Where would I begin to diagnose something like this? Perhaps there is a control that is calling for a different DPI or something?

Comment: This article might help you: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks. I'll be honest - I've been grappling with scaling/DPI related issues for YEARS, and I have never fully got my head round it. The documentation does it's best to explain it, but I somehow fail at absorbing the confusion

Comment: Read the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103)

Comment: Since the OP says that this is an old project I assume it uses .NET Framework <= 4.8. If someone is using .NET >= 6.0, DPI awareness is handled differently there. See: [What's new for .NET 6 (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/whats-new/net60).

Comment: as a workaround, you might want to look at suggestion 3 here: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-scaling-high-dpi-screens/