# High DP scaling override winforms

Tags: windows, winforms, dpi

We have an application which displays fine when using windows display settings 100% but not when for example set to 125%. It is a lot of work to fix this in code (setting AutoScaleMode etc; also have some older 3rd party controls which might be a problem) so looking for another solution.

There is a setting for an application in properties/compatibility to "High DPI scaling override". For example Application (will not scale and remain the same size as with 100%) or "System" or "System (enhanced)". If I change to use for example System (enhanced) the application will scale fine and all labels and controls are correctly scaled.

However since this application is deployed using click-once we can't use that. So looking to to the same with code or app.config settings.

I am aware of the DpiAwareness config settings but does not give same result as using "High DPI scaling override". It looks a lot better but not as good as with "High DPI Scaling override". And AFAIK there is no setting which well let you set the equivalent of High DP override= Application.

So what I am looking is to be able to do the same as "High DPI Scaling override" does but with code / app.config/ manifest setting.

I have also tried to add this to manifest file which is almost working:

```
  <asmv3:windowsSettings>
    <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</dpiAware>
    <gdiScaling xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2017/WindowsSettings">true</gdiScaling>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
```

This almost works with one exception. We have one form with an embedded browser and that does not display correctly (which it does when using the "High DPI scaling override").

Another option is to use a registry hack (setting "High DPI scaling override" actually set a registry setting) in AppCompatFlags\Layers. But if I can do it other than setting this in registry it would be better.

Edit:

I was wrong about "System enhanced" (set with "high DPI scaling override". Now when I run it it did show the same behavior as the above manifest setting (but when I first tried it did work. Don't understand why).

However I found a manifest setting which did work:

```
    <asmv3:windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">unaware</dpiAwareness>
   </asmv3:windowsSettings>
```

Comment: Read the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103) (to the last paragraph)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. Do you mean the dll calls or the assemblyinfo setting? The assemblyinfo setting isn't that only for WPF? I did however found manifest settings to get the behavior I wanted (see my edit). Do you know of any problems using that approach?

Comment: The entry in the `Assemblyinfo` is for WPF elements. Since you mentioned a WebBrowser Control that *misbehaves*, it might be a WPF Control, or a Control that uses PresentationFramework assemblies. If you can use the Manifest (i.e., this is not an add-in), then it's ok, it's the standard method used in .NET Framework (you didn't mentioned the .NET version you're targeting). If you cannot use the Manifest (or it becomes irrelevant in some use-cases), then you can PInvoke, as described in that post

Comment: The misbehaving control (when using the first set of manifest settings) was a webview2 control (embedded edge browser). The application is winforms (.NET 4.8) but also have some forms which are WPF (which seems to work fine using the manifest settings). Pinvoke method might still be an option, the actual deployed client (I tested manifest using our client we use for development work which have an embedded manifest file) is a click-once installation and I think manifest file is generated by our build server so not sure how easy it is to change.

Comment: I just tested using the Pinvoke method (using Context_unaware) and that worked fine. Less hassle than changing the manifest file.

Comment: That's one of reasons why in .NET 6+ the DpiAwareness or the application is set in default initialization procedure, `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize()`, which in turn calls `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext` or `SetProcessDpiAwareness`, depending on the Windows version

Comment: A bit funny it is used in .NET 6+, they say "It is recommended that you set the process-default DPI awareness via application manifest, not an API call.".